# Coworker has knowledge that I could use but they have problems staying on topic

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, communication, colleagues

I have a coworker who has a lot of expertise I could learn from. This coworker often offers to share this knowledge with me and is very generous with his time.

Unfortunately, I cannot follow his way of explaining things. This is not a problem unique to me. And the meetings we have end up being extremely long and off-topic.

I am thinking I should start declining these meetings outright, citing busyness. I don’t want to be someone who isn’t willing to learn, though. Much of these tidbits are things I can’t really look up elsewhere and are specific to our org.

Is it worthwhile to try to continue these meetings but frequently interrupt to stay on-topic or ask for clarification? This would require near constant interruption. Or is it better to just refuse the meetings and do my best without them?

Comment: If you continue these meetings but frequently interrupt to stay on-topic or ask for clarification, not only will you gain much valuable information, but he will learn a great deal too. You should tell him that you think he wanders off topic too much, and get his agreement to allow you to help him teach better.

Comment: Is it the language barrier (you and he do not speak the same native languages to begin with) ? - Or is it just that he does not have very good and effective communication skills ? - Or is it because he assumes that you already have great background knowledge and therefore, he does not spend lots of time to go over small details ?

Comment: @Job_September_2020 I am almost certain he has ADHD, although he has not disclosed this to me. We both speak the same native language. He struggles very severely to stay on topic for even short lengths of time. It has caused him issues with others as well.

Comment: It would be good to mention the specific behaviours you mention here in the question itself. It seems like a very relevant question to me. Instead of the speculative ADHD diagnosis, just mention specific behaviours, eg going off on tangents in unstructured ways.

Comment: I edited your title, because to me the former title indicated that your coworker has problems with speech, a language barrier, is mumbling or has problems with their the voice software. You clarified that that is not the case, it's about the topic of the conversation, not the actual understanding of their words.

Answer (score 4):

Interrupt them with questions to bring them back to the topic which interests you.

> The Thingamabobulator is important, because it keeps the Thingamabobs running. If a thingamabob stops, then bad stuff happens. Just like when my son Bobby doesn't do his homework. He just got another D in math. I really need to tell him to...

> ...excuse me, but you just said that if a thingamabob stops, then bad stuff happens. What kind of bad stuff?

> Yes, for example, the wad with the thingamies overflows, and they all fall onto the floor. Last time that happened we had a meeting where the boss was so angry, she almost got a heart attack. She has to watch out with that. She had a heart attack before, and was in the hospital for weeks. Did you visit a cardiologist lately? Taking care of your health is important...

> I know, but let's get back to that thingamy incident. How did you deal with the spill?

> We took down the whole facility, got the thingamy picker from closet 7G and picked them all up manually and back into the thingamies wad. When they are dirty, you can clean them with ethanol. But when they get wet with water, you have to throw them away. Just like I threw away my paper weight collection. I just read that book which says that if things don't make you happy you should...

> Wait, I have a question about those thingamies. Why is it important that they don't get into contact with water?

...and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Continue engaging, but run the agenda yourself.

As you realize here, not everyone has great communication or organizational skills, and continuing to plow time into an ineffective process is not going to help.

You could spend the same amount of time much more effectively by spending half the time on your own preparation and then running the sessions quite closely. Specifically, lay out topics you know you need to know more about, and try to cover one meeting per topic with close questioning. Then try to use whatever you understood in building your own view of the system, including your own short documentation (eg a diagram). Integrate that into the next session and let him feed back on it. Communicate to him clearly ahead of time: "I can see you have a lot of expertise, and I want to learn from you, but the current format of these sessions does not work for me. I need to structure things differently to make good use of this time."

Other things to try:

- Ask him to produce something in writing instead. (Joe Strazzere suggestion in comments). Could be a lottery, a lot of poor verbal communicators can't write well either, but if this person can, it would help a lot.
- Get him to draw a diagram in the meeting, on a whiteboard or similar. Drill down forensically on particular ambiguities in the diagram. Create your own version of the diagram and bring it back to the next meeting.
- Get him to walkthrough a specific explanatory piece of code. This keeps him anchored to a particular context. Unit tests are good starting points because they give windows into the explicit or implicit APIs.
- Question closely in the meeting, and don't be afraid to bring him back to points you didn't catch.
- Don't go over an hour, and manage the clock yourself. This will probably be a more exhausting process for both of you, but it won't be a waste of time any more, so the value will become clear quickly.